# Splitting out a cost dynamically across weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I’m creating an interim table in SQL Server for use with PowerBI to query financial data.

I have a finance transactions table tblfinance with

```
            CREATE TABLE TBLFinance
            (ID int,
            Value float,
            EntryDate date,
            ClientName varchar (250) 
            )

INSERT INTO TBLFinance(ID ,Value ,EntryDate ,ClientName)
                VALUES(1,'1783.26','2018-10-31 00:00:00.000','Alpha')
                , (2,'675.3','2018-11-30 00:00:00.000','Alpha')
                , (3,'243.6','2018-12-31 00:00:00.000','Alpha')
                , (4,'8.17','2019-01-31 00:00:00.000','Alpha')
                , (5,'257.23','2019-01-31 00:00:00.000','Alpha')
                , (6,'28','2019-02-28 00:00:00.000','Alpha')
                , (7,'1470.61','2019-03-31 00:00:00.000','Bravo')
                , (8,'1062.86','2019-04-30 00:00:00.000','Bravo')
                , (9,'886.65','2019-05-31 00:00:00.000','Bravo')
                , (10,'153.31','2019-05-31 00:00:00.000','Bravo')
                , (11,'150.24','2019-06-30 00:00:00.000','Bravo')
                , (12,'690.14','2019-07-31 00:00:00.000','Charlie')
                , (13,'21.67','2019-08-31 00:00:00.000','Charlie')
                , (14,'339.29','2018-10-31 00:00:00.000','Charlie')
                , (15,'807.96','2018-11-30 00:00:00.000','Delta')
                , (16,'48.94','2018-12-31 00:00:00.000','Delta')
```

I’m calculating transaction values that fall within a week. My week ends on a Sunday, so I have the following query:
                INSERT INTO tblAnalysis
                (WeekTotal
                , WeekEnd
                , Client
                )

```
            SELECT SUM (VALUE) AS WeekTotal
            ,  dateadd (day, case when datepart (WEEKDAY, EntryDate) = 1 then 0 else 8 - datepart (WEEKDAY, EntryDate) end, EntryDate) AS WeekEnd
            , ClientName as Client
            FROM dbo.tblFinance
            GROUP BY dateadd (day, case when datepart (WEEKDAY, EntryDate) = 1 then 0 else 8 - datepart (WEEKDAY, EntryDate) end, EntryDate), CLIENTNAME
```

I’ve now been informed that some of the costs incurred within a given week maybe monthly, and therefore need to be split into 4 weeks, or annually, so split into 52 weeks. I will write a case statement to update the costs based on ClientName, so assume there is an additional field called ‘Payfrequency’.
I want to avoid having to pull the values affected into a temp table, and effectively write this – because there’ll be different sums applied depending on frequency.

```
            SELECT *
             INTO #MonthlyCosts
             FROM 
             ( 
             SELECT 
            client
            , VALUE / 4 AS VALUE 
            , WEEKENDING
              FROM tblAnalysis

                UNION 
                SELECT 
                client
                , nt_acnt 
                , VALUE / 4 AS VALUE 
                , DATEADD(WEEK,1,WEEKENDING) AS WEEKENDING 
                  FROM tblAnalysis
              UNION 
                   SELECT 
                client

                , VALUE / 4 AS VALUE 
                , DATEADD(WEEK,2,WEEKENDING) AS WEEKENDING 
                  FROM tblAnalysis
             UNION 
                   SELECT 
                client

                , VALUE / 4 AS VALUE 
                , DATEADD(WEEK,3,WEEKENDING) AS WEEKENDING 
                  FROM tblAnalysis
            ) AS A
```

I know I need a stored procedure to hold variables so the calculations can be carried out dynamically, but have no idea where to start.

Comment: IMHO you should try to better explain the question, to clearly reference the structure of all the involved tables and better specify the result you want to obtain (may be with an example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursive CTEs to split the data:

```
with cte as (
      select ID, Value, EntryDate, ClientName, payfrequency, 1 as n
      from TBLFinance f
      union all
      select ID, Value, EntryDate, ClientName, payfrequency, n + 1
      from cte
      where n < payfrequency
     )
select *
from cte;
```

Note that by default this is limited to 100 recursion steps.  You can add `option (maxrecursion 0)` for unlimited numbers of days.

Comment: thank you, I ended up writing something very similar, and adding value/payfrequency within the cte to get the recurring split value

Comment: @asher . . . (1) I've been doing this much longer than 10 years.  (2) I've written databases.  (3) I've written books on SQL.  (4) I've designed and taught books on SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to make use of a numbers table. If you can create a table on your server with one column holding a sequence of integer numbers.
You can then use it like this for your weekly values:

```
SELECT 
     client
    , VALUE / 52 AS VALUE 
    , DATEADD(WEEK,N.Number,WEEKENDING) AS WEEKENDING 
    FROM tblAnalysis AS A
    CROSS JOIN tblNumbers AS N
WHERE NCHAR.Number <=52
```